# Jest: Does not allow mocked method to be overwritten

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

Given the following test code:

```js
import { MyParentClass } from "MyParentClass";
import { MyClass } from "MyClass";

MyClass.prototype.post = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({token: '12345'}));

it('first test: this test will be successful tested ✓', async() => {
    const myParentClass = new MyParentClass();
    await expect(myParentClass.run()).toEqual({token: '12345'});
})

it('second test: this test will fail ×', async () => {
    MyClass.prototype.post = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject({message: 'An error ocurred'}));
    const myParentClass = new MyParentClass();
    await expect(myParentClass.run()).rejects.toEqual({message: 'success'});
})
```

The "`run`" method internally makes use of the '`MyClass`' class and its "`post`" method. When I run a code like this, for my second test, I get a message like the following:

`"Received promise resolved instead of rejected"`

I understand that when the answer for the "`post`" method is globally defined, it will always take that value, but I also understand that in the second test `I am overwriting` the behavior of that method, why don't you take it into account?

I know I can also use `jest.doMock`, but I don't understand the documentation well, could someone help me understand it to apply it to my example?

Answer (score 1):

Using [asyncFn](https://medium.com/houston-io/how-to-unit-test-asynchronous-code-for-javascript-in-2020-41c124be2552) as so will solve the problem, and additionally simplify the test by making it read in chronological order.

```
import asyncFn from '@asyncFn/jest';

describe('myParentClass', () => {
  let parentClass;
  let runPromise;

  beforeEach(() => {
    parentClass = new MyParentClass();
    parentClass.post = asyncFn();
    runPromise = myParentClass.run();
  });      

  it('first test: this test will be successful tested ✓', () => {
    parentClass.post.resolve({ token: '12345' });

    return expect(runPromise).resolves.toEqual({ token: '12345' });
  })

  it('second test: this test will fail ×', () => {
    parentClass.post.reject({ message: 'An error occured'} );

    return expect(runPromise).rejects.toEqual({ message: 'An error occured' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mockImplementationOnce` or `mockReturnValueOnce` since you've already converted `post` to a jest mock function. So you could do something like this on your 2nd test:

```
it('second test: this test will fail ×', async () => {
  MyClass.prototype.post.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject({message: 'An error ocurred'}));
  const myParentClass = new MyParentClass();
  await expect(myParentClass.run()).rejects.toEqual({message: 'An error ocurred'});
})
```